# Does FFmpeg download the video on server to generate screen shot from S3 video url?

Tags: ffmpeg, screenshot, thumbnails, video-thumbnails

I am running the following command to generate screenshot from an S3 video url in my server. I want to know if FFmpeg downloads the video to server disk or memory before generating the screenshot. Let me know if anyone knows about this, thanks.

```
ffmpeg -i "http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/video.mp4" -ss 00:00:10 -vframes 1 -f image2 "screeenshot.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

With demuxer seek, `-ss` before `-i`, ffmpeg will download the header of the MP4, get the offset of the sought frame and download from that point onwards. With output seek, `-ss` after `-i`, ffmpeg will download all media data from start of file till all frames required for output are read.